# Add class when on second onepage-page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a website (one page) and when you scroll down, the second page scrolls over the first page. The background-color of the second page is a little bit transparant (0.9) so you can still see the first page.

I want the div with text on the first page and the logo to have an extra class when the second page is scrolled over the first page so I can make the text and logo disappear.

I tried to use jQuery's inview function, but due to an absolute position, the first page isn't really out of the viewport.

If someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an onLeave event in the doc that receive a nextIndex value:

```
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['home', 'work', 'contact'],
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
            if(nextIndex === 1) {
                  $('body').removeClass('foo');
            } else {
                  $('body').addClass('foo');
            }
        }
    });
```

This will add the foo class on page 2, 3, ... and remove it on first page.

Advise: instead of:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home', 'work', 'contact'],
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script src="js/formvalidation.js"></script>
    <script src="http://use.typekit.net/mye6dqa.js"></script>
    <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    <script>
    required.add('Full_Name','NOT_EMPTY','Full Name');
    required.add('Email_Address','EMAIL','Email Address');
    required.add('Your_Message','NOT_EMPTY','Your Message');
    </script>
    <script>
            function getURLParameter(name) {
              return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
            } 
            var succesvar = getURLParameter("succesful");
    </script>
```

You can do:

```
    <script src="js/formvalidation.js"></script>
    <script src="http://use.typekit.net/mye6dqa.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home', 'work', 'contact'],
            });
        });
        try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}
        required.add('Full_Name','NOT_EMPTY','Full Name');
        required.add('Email_Address','EMAIL','Email Address');
        required.add('Your_Message','NOT_EMPTY','Your Message');
        function getURLParameter(name) {
              return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
            } 
            var succesvar = getURLParameter("succesful");
    </script>
```

Or with another file:

```
    <script src="js/formvalidation.js"></script>
    <script src="http://use.typekit.net/mye6dqa.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

With js/main.js:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['home', 'work', 'contact'],
            });
        });
        try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
        required.add('Full_Name','NOT_EMPTY','Full Name');
        required.add('Email_Address','EMAIL','Email Address');
        required.add('Your_Message','NOT_EMPTY','Your Message');
        function getURLParameter(name) {
              return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
            } 
            var succesvar = getURLParameter("succesful");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thank you for the tips as well. I tried a different file, but that didn't work. I merged them into one script now.

Comment: Check the path of your file: js/main.js will become http://wensinkdesign.nl/update/js/main.js. /js/main.js will become http://wensinkdesign.nl/js/main.js, put the file where you want and set the path as needed.